# How to sort data into new columns based on information in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data on fiddler crabs that includes which of its claws are dominate (L or R) (listed as handedness), and the length of specific walking legs (the merus) on each side, which are again sorted by L and R.

| Merus_L | Merus_R | Handedness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13.300 | 10.950 | R |
| 9.980 | 12.250 | L |
| 8.750 | 12.150 | L |

What I want is to have a column (or a way) to sort these merus values by whether they were on the same side as the major claw (aka dominate claw). for example, if you go back to the above table, the first crab is right handed, so I would like the Merus_R data to be listed under a column called "Major_merus", and the data from Merus_L to be listed under "Minor_merus".
the correct sorting is shown below:

| Major_merus | Minor_merus | Handedness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.950 | 13.300 | R |
| 9.980 | 12.250 | L |
| 8.750 | 12.150 | L |

I've already tried the `ifelse` command recommended by my professor, but I don't know how to use the new data, or why only the Major_merus is correct now.

```
Morphdata$Major_merus<-ifelse(Morphdata$Handedness=="L","Merus_L","Merus_R")
Morphdata$Minor_merus<-ifelse(Morphdata$Handedness=="R","Merus_R","Merus_L")
```

| Major_merus | Minor_merus |
| --- | --- |
| Merus_R | Merus_R |
| Merus_L | Merus_L |
| Merus_L | Merus_L |

Sorry if this formatting is incorrect, it's my first post!

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are trying to do here. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by your question. The best I could conclude was that you want to group the data by handedness and major merus, but all of your data will have major merus values if thats the case.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I tried to make it a little clearer in the second paragraph

Comment: Ok then the second dataframe is your desired output, right?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the solution, I guess this one is more straight forward:

- For `Major_mercus` column, I first created a customized name with `paste0` by concatenating `Merus_` with the value of `Handedness` in every row. Then I retrieve the value with `get` function
- For `Minor_mercus` I basically did the same but I used `ifelse` to first swap the `R` and `L` value in each row and then retrieve the desired value

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Major_mercus = get(paste0("Merus_", Handedness)),
         Minor_mercus = get(paste0("Merus_", ifelse(Handedness == "R", "L", "R")))) %>%
  select(ends_with("mercus"), Handedness)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  Major_mercus Minor_mercus Handedness
         <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>     
1        11.0          13.3 R         
2         9.98         12.2 L         
3         8.75         12.2 L
```